# Sometimes can't select list item with single click

Tags: list, extjs, sencha-touch-2

For one of my Sencha Touch lists clicking on an item doesn't always select it. The first click on the list will always select that item, but when you click on another item after that it often won't select until you click another time. During testing I've been very careful to not move the cursor while clicking.

There's no listener on the list, another event will look at the selected item. I've added a listener to test this better, shows the same thing. Also the selected list item stays selected after the ignored click.

I can't reproduce this with a Fiddle and with other lists every item can always be selected with a single click.

The actual list only has 2 items, but they get a lot more data than the 80 pixels item height, one is almost 400 pixels high. But only showing little data doesn't help.

```
Ext.define('App.view.MyList',
{
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'mylist',
    alias: 'widget.mylist',

    config:
    {
        cls: 'oddEvenList',
        store: 'myStore',
        itemHeight: 80,
        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<table width="100%">' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td width="180px">' +
                        'User name:' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td width="180px">' +
                        '{UserName}' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
            '</table>')
    }
});

.oddEvenList {
    .x-list-item {
        //background-color: #FFF !important;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $base-grey-border !important;

        &:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: $light-grey;
        }

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        padding: 0, 7px, 0, 7px !important;
        margin: 5px, 0, 5px, 0 !important;
    }

    .x-item-selected {
        background: {
            image: none !important;
            color: #a6c060 !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why are you extending from `Ext.dataview.List`, and not from `Ext.dataview.DataView`? Seeing your code there is no need to extend from the (much heavier list).

Answer (score 0):

Remove config property and Write code without config property and then check.